# New inspiron is OverHeating on 20.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, dell, fan, overheating

I bought a DELL Inspiron 5518 (16gb, 512gb + Nvidia MX450) this year. **The laptop officially supports Ubuntu**.
I dual booted the Windows with Ubuntu **20.04** but there is very high difference between usage.

On windows, it sustains upto 5-6 hours of usage with negligible heating on the upper keyboard side (where fans are)

But on ubuntu, **it barely resists 1.5 hours and the upper right part of keyboard is so much heated that a finger can't be kept there for long.**

I installed `lmsensors` and did `sensors-detect`.
It prompted only `coretemp` to add to `/etc/modules` and I did the same

There was no fan info when running `sensors`.

**Important Update**
Some observations I have made now

1. `sensors` show very normal temperature even when it is blazing hot. So, I thought maybe battery is hot. but `acpitool` shows temp unavailable.
2. The fans are running at high noise on ubuntu and silent on Windows.
3. `tlp`, `thermald` etc are not making any effect.
4. `nvidia-settings` is not available. When installed it is blank meaning nvidia is not detected. Settings show GPU is Intel Iris.
   `sudo prime-select query` show `on-demand`. There was no effect when i changed it to `nvidia` hence I changed it to `intel` to be on safe side.
5. The system is up-to-date and also did `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.

**Attempt**

I found out that the power settings can be corrected by imitating that it is a windows system in Grub by

in `/etc/default/grub`, I had

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

I experimented with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=!Windows 2020"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2020'"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=! \"acpi_osi=Windows 2020\" "
(P.S. this was the solution all along, see answer below)
```

but to no avail.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Do you have nvidia drivers installed? They're not installed automatically (https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

Comment: @MatiasNGoldberg Yes it is using the recommended Nvidia driver but `nvidia-settings` or `nvidia-smi` give error.

Comment: Have you tried installing NVIDIA using the installer? (via https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx). Select the nouveau driver again on Ubuntu, and then install NVIDIA's drivers from its website (warning: if something goes wrong during installation xorg may no longer run on boot and you'll have to run `nvidiainstaller --uninstall` from CLI to fix it).

Comment: @MatiasNGoldberg I tried now and it recommends to install the NVIDIA driver by selecting the Nvidia option in Additional Drivers (which I changed to naoveau) rather than through the installer.

Comment: Have a look at `powertop`. You can tab through to the 'Tunables' section to tweak a few things. The other thing I would try is a BIOS update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tremendous research and experimenting, I found the solution to this problem.

The problem seems to be the compatibility between the Bios/Grub power-management and Ubuntu. For example, the ACPI DSDT expects some different OS and we are running some different OS.

Now as I mentioned in the question about experimenting with `/etc/default/grub`, I was actually missing a very important step and that was to check the version of Windows OSI that is actually supported by my device power management.

(It has to be Windows because the laptop performs excellent on Windows, hence our objective is to fake Ubuntu as Windwos to the device)

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26747559

As mentioned in above article, the supported Window OSI can be found by

```
sudo strings /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/DSDT | grep -i 'windows ' | sort
```

```
Microsoft Windows NT
Windows 2001
Windows 2001
Windows 2001.1
Windows 2001 SP1
Windows 2001 SP2
Windows 2006
Windows 2006
Windows 2009
Windows 2009
Windows 2012
Windows 2012
Windows 2013
Windows 2013
Windows 2015
Windows 2015
```

So, now this was the final edit I made in the `/etc/default/grub` file.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=! \"acpi_osi=Windows 2015\" "
```

And by this, the overheating as well as battery issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are very nice but I think you may be having a hardware problem. I mention just in case as it is a dangerous situation as battery may explode.

Image attached
[image]

I had a battery swallowing on a dell xps and the fans where overworking to try to cope with the temperature.

Also, pointing only a Software problem, with my laptops I've seen that battery on Windows last more than in Linux, although the proportion was not so huge as in your case.
You should check the processes running in Linux:

`ps -aux`
`htop`
`top`

Sort by CPU.

Some processes may be using more CPU, causing heating, making the fans work hard, and that drains a lot of battery.

Cheers